# typescript error - 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: javascript, sorting, typescript, compiler-errors

Can anybody help me.

I am trying to sort strings from array

```
var someArray= ["3a445a_V1", "3", "2a33s454_V1", "1", "3_V2", "2s4a34s3_V2", "234343"];

const [record] = someArray.map(r => parseFloat(r.replace('_V','.'))).sort((a,b) => a < b);

console.log(record)
//it returns 3a445a.1
```

[JFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zautub83/4/)

In browser console.log it works fine, not in typescript?

typescript it is giving below error
**Error:**

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(a: number, b: number) => boolean' is not 
assignable to parameter of type '(a: number, b: number) => number'.
      Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: `(a,b) => a < b` is not a valid comparison function. As typescript says, it's supposed to return a number, not a boolean.

Comment: *"In browser console.log it works fine'* It doesn't, actually, it just happens that your data don't reveal the problems with it.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder , i have just created fiddle, please check and guide me

Comment: @t.j. im still wondering how i overlooked that...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`.sort((a,b) => a < b)` is incorrect. The TypeScript message is right: The `sort` callback should return a **number**, not a boolean.

Instead: `.sort((a,b) => a - b)` (`-` instead of `<`). Or `b - a` to sort the other way. This is because the `sort` callback should return a negative number if `a` comes before `b`, `0` if their order doesn't matter, and a positive number if `b` comes before `a`. Since you seem to want ascending order, that's `a - b` so that if `a` is less than `b`, it returns a negative number, etc. `b - a` does a descending sort.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that I could just write b - a!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `.sort((a,b) => Number(a>b))`. This worked for me just fine.